# How can I get the absolute path of a running .exe in java web application?

Tags: java, path, absolute-path

I want to get the absolute path of a .exe and I used `file.getAbsolutePath()` but give me

```
Users/Username/Documents/workspaceN/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/NameProject/lib/name.exe
```

but I only want this:

```
/Users/Username/Documents/workspaceN/NameProject/lib/name.exe
```

How can I do this? It runs correctly in Java application but in web application it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

> but I only want this:

```
/Users/Username/Documents/workspaceN/NameProject/lib/name.exe
```

> How can I do this? In **Java application** run correctly but in **web application** not.

First of all web application is a Java (EE) application.

Second: `/Users/Username/Documents/workspaceN/NameProject/lib/name.exe` is not the real path of your file. You are getting the real path where the `.exe` file is placed into the packaged application; `WAR` file.

If you want another path you must use the `.exe` file as an external resource and reference it directly from the code, don't include it in the war package.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use this path because an external library wants liked `/Users/Username/Documents/workspaceN/NameProject/lib/name.exe` to run, otherwise launches an exception

Comment: @ElianaPalermiti please read carefully my answer, what you need is to use exe as external resource, or reconfigure the external library... Getting another `absolutePath` means file is placed in another folder